# Yield stop the action by penetrating a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I read such a minimal demonstration about coroutine [A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/)

```
def countdown(n):
    print("Counting down from", n)
    while n > 0:
        yield n
        n -= 1
#why it stop?
x = countdown(10)
#no output was produced
```

I print no result, when first call it.

```
In [10]: x                                                                                                        
Out[10]: <generator object countdown at 0x1036e4228>
```

but should

```
In [14]: next(x)                                                                                                  
Out[14]: Counting down from 10
In [15]: next(x)                                                                                                  
Out[15]: 1
In [16]: next(x)
```

Why `print("Counting down from", n)`not executed directly when i invoke the function `countdown()`.

I think the `Counting down from 10` should be executed whatever yield, it is a sequential process.

What stop `print("Counting down from", n)` running, I am aware that

```
do something yield
```

yield will stop the action ahead of it,

but in the countdown example, how could `yield` stop `print("Counting down from", n)` by penetrating the while loop

Comment: Your code behaves exactly as expected. Your question is unclear.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions can help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The two input and output snippets show you creating a generator `x`, and then later you show the last few `next` calls on it (though you appear to have cut off the exception that would follow the last `next` call). But you've omitted the first `next` call, which is where you'd see the `Counting down from 10` output. Can you explain some more about what you're confused by?

Comment: why print not executed? @Blckknght

Comment: It will be executed, in the part of the interactive session you've omitted from the question. The very first time you call `next(x)`, it will print the message.

Comment: Yes, I know, but why only execute when next(x),  I have already call the function with countdown(10), so the first should run letting alone yield. @Blckknght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you expect to see the `Counting down from 10` text printed out immediately when you call `countdown(10)`. But that reflects a misunderstanding of how generator functions work.

A `yield` expression isn't something that just interrupts the control flow of a normal function. Rather, any function that contains a `yield` anywhere in it becomes a generator function, which works differently than a normal function.

When you call a generator function, none of its code runs immediately. Instead, Python just creates a generator object that encapsulates the state of the function call (which at first will just record that you're at the very top of the function which hasn't started running yet). The generator object is what gets returned to the caller.

It is only after you call `next` on the generator object that function's code starts to run. It will run until it comes to a `yield` expression, and the value being `yield`ed is what the `next` will return. The state of the running function is saved as part of the generator object, and it remains paused until you call `next` on it again.

The important thing to note is that the generator object doesn't ever run ahead of a `yield` until the outside code is done with the yielded value and asks for another one. We use generator functions specifically because they are lazy!

Here's a simple script that might help you understand how it works better than your example generator that tries to do something more useful:

```
import time

def generator_function():
    print("generator start")
    yield 1
    print("generator middle")
    yield 2
    print("generator end")

print("creating the generator")
generator_object = generator_function()

print("taking a break")
time.sleep(1)

print("getting first value")
val1 = next(generator_object)
print("got", val1)

print("taking a break")
time.sleep(1)

print("getting second value")
val2 = next(generator_object)
print("got", val2)

print("taking a break")
time.sleep(1)

print("try getting a third value (it won't work)")
try:
    val3 = next(generator_object)   # note, the assignment never occurs, since next() raises
    print("got", val3)              # this line won't ever be reached
except Exception as e:
    print("got an exception instead of a value:", type(e))
```

The print statements from the generator will always appear between the "getting" and "got" messages from the outer code.

Comment: ty, "When you call a generator function, none of its code runs immediately.` click with me. it perform as a decorator.